# Import CSV into org-mode table, but preserve quotes around strings

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table

I really like the ability to quickly go between CSV tables like this:

```
a, b, c
this, TRUE, 5,
that, FALSE, 8
```

...and org mode tables, that look like this:

```
| a    | b     | c |
| this | TRUE  | 5 |
| that | FALSE | 8 |
```

...using `org-table-create-or-convert-from-region`.

However, I often work with CSV files where the strings are quoted, i.e.:

```
a,b,c
"this",TRUE,5
"that",FALSE,8
```

Converting this to an org mode table gives:

```
| a    | b     | c |
| this | TRUE  | 5 |
| that | FALSE | 8 |
```

...which means that when converting *back* to CSV, I lose the quoting of "this" and "that".

Is there a simple way to import CSV tables into org mode while preserving quotes around strings (i.e. cells would like like `| "this" |`)?

Comment: There are many slightly different formats called CSV, but in the most common one, a field `"blah"` is exactly equivalent to just plain `blah`, so it doesn't matter that those quotes aren't preserved. The org export function do put quotes when they are necessary, such as when one field contains a comma or a quote character.